# Can't add file extension restriction on webdav server (apache)

Tags: apache2, webdav

I have configured a webdav server on Ubuntu 22.04 using apache. Here is my configuration file in the sites-enabled folder, and it works like that:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin %%EMAIL%%
        ServerName %%DOMAIN%%
        DocumentRoot %%PATH%%
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /webdav /var/www/webdav

        <Directory /var/www/webdav>
            DAV On

AuthType Digest
AuthName "webdav"
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/var/users.password
Require valid-user
    SetHandler None
    Options None
    AllowOverride None


        </Directory>


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/%%DOMAIN%%/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/%%DOMAIN%%/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that it allows to add php files for instances, and those files can be executed by calling or editing them in webdav. This is a clear security issue.

I have tried to add :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php|jsp|cgi|pl|py)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Both inside the Directory tag and outside, but, after restarting apache or even the whole server I get a 403 Forbidden when trying to connect with cadaver :

```
cadaver %%URL%%
Authentication required for webdav on server `%%URL%%':
Username: %%USERNAME%%
Password: %%PASSWORD%%
Could not open collection:
403 Forbidden
dav:/webdav/?
```

Whereas when I remove the FileMatch tag I don't get an error and can connect.

Here are the apache2 error logs when restarting apache and having added the FileMatch tag (I have this logs if I remove the FileMatch tag too) :

```
[Sun Sep 03 20:14:01.728312 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1259] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Sep 03 20:14:01.821721 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1465] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Sep 03 20:14:01.821792 2023] [core:notice] [pid 1465] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

And here are the logs when I try to connect (I don't have these logs if I remove the FilesMatch tag) :

```
[Sun Sep 03 20:15:40.271797 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 1467] [client %%IP%%:44836] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/webdav/index.cgi
[Sun Sep 03 20:15:40.271967 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 1467] [client %%IP%%:44836] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/webdav/index.pl
[Sun Sep 03 20:15:40.272037 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 1467] [client %%IP%%:44836] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/webdav/index.php
```